# Objc-C: RACObserve rapidly changing values (RACSignal for AFHTTPRequestOperation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, afhttprequestoperation

I am using reactive cocoa to create download file from server. I have a **DownloadMapFileOperation.m** file with a progress property (progress value, currentBytes, totalBytes). It changes very rapidly in my next `RACSignal` method and float progress (it's unnecesarry, but

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableDictionary *progressDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) float progress;
```

and `RACSignal` creating method

```
- (RACSignal *)signalForDownloadMap:(Place *)place
{
    return [[[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        NSString *mapUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl/%@", place.mapFileName];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mapUrlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        _downloadFileOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];

        [_downloadFileOperation setOutputStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:fullPath append:NO]];

        [_downloadFileOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id response)
         {
             NSLog(@"Downloaded via compl block");
             [subscriber sendNext:nil];
             [subscriber sendCompleted];

         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             [subscriber sendError:error];
         }];

        @weakify(self)
        self.progressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.progressDictionary[@"progress"] = @(0);
        self.progressDictionary[@"current"] = @(0);
        self.progressDictionary[@"total"] = @(0);
        self.progress = @(0);

        [_downloadFileOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
         {
             @strongify(self)
             self.progressDictionary[@"current"] = @(totalBytesRead);
             self.progressDictionary[@"total"] = @(totalBytesExpectedToRead);
             self.progressDictionary[@"progress"] = @((float)totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
             self.progress = @((float)totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
             self.progress = @((float)totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
         }];

        [_downloadFileOperation start];
        return nil;
    }] filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        return !(.mapFileName == nil);
    }]
        deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]
    ];
}
```

I just want to show the progress in my view via `RACObserve` in my ViewController.

```
[[[DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance] signalForDownloadMap:self.place]
     subscribeNext:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
        NSString *alertMessage = @"Download complete";
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        downloadMapView.progressLabel.text = @"Download Complete";
    }];

    [[[DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance] signalForDownloadMap:self.place] subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    }];

    RAC(downloadMapView, progressView.progress) = [RACObserve([DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance], progress)
                                                   map:^id(id value) {
                                                       return value;
                                                   }];

  RAC(downloadMapView, progressLabel.text) = [RACObserve([DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance], progressDictionary)
                                                    map:^id(NSDictionary *value) {
                                                        return [value[@"progress"] isEqual: @(1)] ? @"Download Complete" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloaded %@ of %@", value[@"current"], value[@"total"]];
                                                    }];
```

But my progress view jumps from 60% to 50% (or 45 - 35 etc.) sometimes and `NSLog(@"Downloaded via compl block");` shows before progress reaches 100% (sometimes it reaches and starts again from about 70%).
And if I use `progressDictionary`(like in the second `RACObserve`) - it doesn't work (shows 0 progress and Downloaded 0 of 0)

**EDITED**

I also try to add methods in my **DownloadMapFileOperation.m** file which pauses, resumes, cancels download operation.

```
- (RACSignal *)signalForPauseDownloadMap
{
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [_downloadFileOperation pause];
        [subscriber sendNext:nil];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return nil;
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)signalForResumeDownloadMap
{
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [_downloadFileOperation resume];
        [subscriber sendNext:nil];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return nil;
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)signalForCancelDownloadMap
{
    return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [_downloadFileOperation cancel];
        [subscriber sendNext:nil];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return nil;
    }] filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        return (_downloadFileOperation);
    }];
}
```

But: My download file operation doesn't stop. When I use in my VC

```
[[_downloadMapFileOperation signalForPauseDownloadMap]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        [downloadMapView setTitleForStartDownloadButton:@"Resume download"];
        _currentDownloadState = kHTDownloadStatePaused;
    }];
```

My progress value works correct (doesn't jump from value to value). Help me out please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your original question about the jumping download progress, the problem is you're creating subscriptions to two copies of the signal, which is resulting in two downloads. Namely, this bit of code:

```
[[[DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance] signalForDownloadMap:self.place]
 subscribeNext:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
    NSString *alertMessage = @"Download complete";
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    downloadMapView.progressLabel.text = @"Download Complete";
}];

[[[DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance] signalForDownloadMap:self.place] subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}];
```

Each `subscribeNext`/`subscribeError`/etc. would create a new subscription, and start a download. What you want to use for subscription is as follows:

```
[[[DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance] signalForDownloadMap:self.place]
 subscribeNext:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
    NSString *alertMessage = @"Download complete";
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    downloadMapView.progressLabel.text = @"Download Complete";
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}];
```

For pause and resume, I don't think creating further signals make sense. If you do have access to the download file operation, then just call pause/resume directly on it. The original subscription will continue to be valid, and should pause/resume updating based on behavior within the created signal.

As for cancellation, what you really want to do is use disposables. In the `[RACSignal createSignal:]` call, you do not want to return `nil`. Instead, set up a disposable that'd cancel the download when the disposable is disposed.

**Edit**:

Ideally you want to send the progress through the signal. In the `setDownloadProgressBlock` you would instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *progressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
progressDictionary[@"current"] = @(totalBytesRead);
progressDictionary[@"total"] = @(totalBytesExpectedToRead);
progressDictionary[@"progress"] = @((float)totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
[subscriber sendNext:[progressDictionary copy]];
```

You would then be able to read the progressDictionary when you subscribe, like so:

```
[[[DownloadMapFileOperation sharedInstance] signalForDownloadMap:self.place]
subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *progressDictionary) {
    // Do stuff with dictionary here, like update UI with progress
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    // Error related stuff
} completed:^{
    // Completed stuff
}];
```

**Note**: you should not be sending nil through sendNext without good reason. Completion logic should only be done in the completion block.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But could you explain how to dispose the signal. I've added return `[RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [_downloadFileOperation cancel];
        }];` instead of `return nil`. And now I have to buttons: 1 subscribes signal `[_signal subscribe...` and the second one should cancel, but I can't use `dispose` without `subscribeNext/error`. And the second question is: why I can't observe dictionary values (**progressDictionary**). If I observing  `float` property (progress) - it works. if I use `progressDictionary[@"progress"]` - it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using buttons, you may want to look into using `RACCommand`s. I'm not sure what may be going wrong with `progressDictionary`, but ideally you don't want to use something like that. Instead of storing a property on `self`, just make your signal emit the progress info. That's more the "RAC" way of doing things.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But I am a new in RAC, so I want to learn some good practice. Could you subscribe me a bit about hot to "emit the progress info". How can I get progress info from block `setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)`. And the second one: I am using delegate pattern for buttons (creating in view, view delegates actions to controller). How can I use `RACCommand` there.

Comment: Edited answer to show an example of how to send stuff through a signal, as well as how to use it on subscription. I think `RACCommand` usage is out of the scope of this question. Feel free to post a new question on SO, but be sure to do so after doing some reading and research.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try to learn. But pause/resume directly to operation (without signals fork very strange). But It out of this question.